# For each line in a file, replace multiple-whitespace substring of variable length with line break

Tags: python, regex, string

Using Python 2.7.1, I read in a file:

```
input = open(file, "rU")
tmp = input.readlines()
```

which looks like this:

```
>name     -----meoidoad
>longname -lksowkdkfg
>nm       --kdmknskoeoe---
>nmee     dowdbnufignwwwwcds--
```

That is, each line has a short substring of whitespaces, but the length of this substring varies by line.

I would like to write script that edits my `tmp` object such that when I write `tmp` to file, the result is

```
>name
-----meoidoad
>longname
-lksowkdkfg
>nm
--kdmknskoeoe---
>nmee
dowdbnufignwwwwcds--
```

I.e. I would like to break each line into two lines, at that substring of whitespaces (and get rid of the spaces in the process).

The starting position of the string *after* the whitespaces is always the same *within* a file, but may vary *among* a large batch of files I am working with. So, I need a solution that does not rely on positions.

I've seen many similar questions on here, with many well-liked answers that use short regex scripts to do so, so it is possible I am duplicating a previous question. However, none of what I've seen so far has worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(re.sub('\s\s+', '\n', line))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't huge (i.e. hundreds of MB), you can do this concisely with `split()` and `join()`:

```
with open(file, 'rU') as f, open(outfilename, 'w') as o:
    o.write('\n'.join(f.read().split()))
```

I would also recommend against naming anything `input`, as that will mask the built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.